# Error with feature to raster conversion in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, arcmap, raster-conversion, serious-application-error

I am trying to convert an ESRI geodatabase into a raster using the 'Feature to raster' conversion tool in ArcMap 10.1. The geodatbase is available publicly from the [USDA Forest Service website](http://www.fs.usda.gov/detail/r5/landmanagement/resourcemanagement/?cid=stelprdb5347192) (South Sierra, zone 4), and I am using the WHRTYPE property to convert it in raster form. The output cell size is set to 30 (see attached picture).

[image]

The problem is that **ArcGIS simply crashes** during the operation, returning a ***serious application error*** popup. No explanations of what went wrong. **A tif file is actually produced**, although the corresponding 'WHRTYPE' field in its attribute table is empty.

[image]

I tested this on two different, quite recent machines and got the same problem. I checked the field for null values. I also disabled background geoprocessing, as suggested in other posts.

**I tested the same process on another geodatabase from the same webpage (South Coast, zone 7) and it worked.** So I am really confused at the moment. Can anyone help me out?

[image]

Comment: It's probably too complex, too many unique values on a scanline or processing block, try clipping to smaller extents then mosaicing the images back together. That or a bad geometry - use Repair Geometry on the input data first... or even better do both!

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson thanks for your comment. I am not 100% sure if this captures the complexity of the objects, but: 1) the first geodatabase (the non-working one) has 53537 features and 46 WHRTYPE classes, 2) the second geodatabase (the working one) has 63681 features and 49 WHRTYPE classes. If it worked on the second one, why did it fail on the first one?

Comment: On a side note, is there something like an automatic sub-sampling option for these kind of operations? Considering the price-tag of ArcGIS, I wasn't expecting to have to do it manually. Perhaps there is a lower-level solution, like using GDAL?

Comment: GDAL also works, http://www.gdal.org/gdal_rasterize.html. Normally ArcGis does an internal *dice* to break features up for operations like Clip etc.. I don't know why it wouldn't also do the same. Also check your temp space (TEMP/TMP environment variable in windows) - these operations are done into the %temp% directory and then copied to the output directory. I've used that approach before successfully but that was to run multiple instances to get it done faster rather than avoid errors.

Comment: If this fails on a Cell Output Size of 30 try using something much larger as a test which may or may not shed some light on whether it is having problems with the input or output.  I'm assuming that it is a Serious Application Error that you are receiving.  If so, I think you should state that explicitly in your question.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed reply guys, but I needed some time to run a couple of tests.
@MichaelMiles-Stimson, Repair Geometry one the input data didn't help. What do you mean by checking the temp space? Should I increase its size?
Thanks!

Comment: @PolyGeo, thanks for your comment. Yes indeed running with a cell output size of 200 works, anything at a finer scale fails. Although I still need a 30 m resolution. Any suggestion?

Comment: The temp directory can sometimes get cluttered and may have size limits (quotas) enforced by system policy. If a process is crashing it may leave fragments as well as sizable grids in your temporary directory that should be removed. You can set your temp elsewhere in command by typing *SET TEMP=c:\some\path* followed by *SET TMP=c:\some\otherpath* standard DOS rules apply: no spaces, paths must exist. Then to launch catalog there type *start arccatalog* in the same DOS window, if you get an error use the whole path to arccatlog.exe. Have you tried GDAL_Rasterize?

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson, thanks for the tip on the TMP directory. That's very good to know for future reference. Unfortunately the trick didn't help solving this specific problem. I also tried `gdal_rasterize` but it returned a raster with all zeros.

Comment: Just to complete the picture, I also tried to dissolve the source database into a shape file using the WHRTYPE field, hoping to simplify the complexity of the object. I retried the rasterization (both ArcGIS or GDAL) on the dissolved vector, but it didn't improve the situation

Comment: Have you tried 'dicing' http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000037000000 the features? They are complex boundaries and a bit of simplification may help. If that still doesn't work, have you tried the cut 'n process operation: clip out to smaller sub areas, rasterize the areas and mosaic the result to a single raster?

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson, thanks once again for showing me a tool I didn't know about. Unfortunately, also in this case, things didn't work out. I diced the dataset with a 1000 limit, and I ended up with my original result: ArcGIS crashes but a raster with an empty 'WHRTYPE' is produced (much faster than before!).

Comment: Then your only resort is to cut into successively smaller blocks, with a little overlap preferably, until you can rasterize the whole dataset in chunks then mosaic. Look at your snapraster environment setting to ensure that cells align during processing and also consider mosaicking_tolerance value to eliminate resampling during mosaic.